# Python if statement is not working

Tags: python

I'm very sorry if it's a super noob question, but I can't even get this to run properly. Am I missing something, I've been searching for 20 mins and I'm getting desperate.

```
num = input()
if num == 3:
  print("yes its 3")
```

Comment: `input()` returns string. You need `int` - `int(input().strip())`

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: In all honesty, please don't get desperate after just 20 minutes of searching. If you pursue any programming course of study or employment, you will have times when you're searching for literally hours about why a process isn't working like its supposed to. Asking for help can be a very good learning tool, but the most valuable thing you can learn right now isn't simply how to program, but how to find answers to your questions. Get familiar with online tutorials and resources and learn how to be more effective searching without getting desperate, and if you learn that, things will go better.

Comment: Right, Sorry. I think I bit more than I could chew on the code I'm working on. I'm just a 10th grader after all.

Comment: Go throught type of input data also, may be type conversation needed

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the types. `num = input()` returns `string`, but you compare it to `int`

you could try to run:

```
num = input()
if num == '3':
  print("yes its 3")
```